# Faster mean calculation in raster stack

Tags: r, mean, raster

I have a stack of some 400 rasters, for which I want to calculate the mean at each cell. I am using the function "mean" in the package raster, but it is taking too long. Is there an alternative function/package to calculate the mean of large stacks?

```
 # brief example
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
logoMean=mean(logo)
```

Comment: `mean(logo)` appears to be quite optimized compared to [my testing](https://gist.github.com/romunov/c9d1ca1628cfbca873679835a90cc395). Perhaps a data.table solution would top it.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your calculations are cell by cell, you can use parallelization. The easiest access to parallel raster processing is via the `clusterR` function in the `raster-package`. This of course only makes sense with raster files sufficiently large enough so the overhead involved does not actually make processing slower.

```
library(raster)
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
ncores <- 4 # define the number of cores you want to use
beginCluster(ncores)
logoMean <- clusterR(logo, mean, args=list(na.rm=TRUE))
endCluster()

logoMean_old <- mean(logo)
identical(logoMean, logoMean_old)
```