# Can I parallelize raster time series functions in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, time-series, raster

I would like to parallelize the `rts::apply.yearly()` function

The regular example given in rts is:

```
library(rts)
file <- system.file("external/ndvi", package="rts")

ndvi <- rts(file) # read the ndvi time series from the specified file
ndvi
ndvi.y <- apply.yearly(ndvi, mean) # apply mean function for each year
ndvi.y
```

When I try to apply a parallel process routine from [r - faster mean calculation in raster stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318164/r-faster-mean-calculation-in-raster-stack):

```
library(parallel)
library(raster)
start <- Sys.time()
ncores <- detectCores(logical = TRUE)
beginCluster(ncores)
ndvi.yPAR <- clusterR(apply.yearly(ndvi, mean))
endCluster()
print(Sys.time() - start)
```

I receive the error: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"SpatRasterTS"’`